# Custom, converted tflite model causing an AudioClassifier crash on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I had a .pb model which I converted to a .tflite model. The .pb model was created very similarly to this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands

This is the code I used to convert it to tflite:

```
path = "/conv_frozen.pb"

input_array = ['wav_data']
output = ['labels_softmax']

converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(path, input_arrays=input_array, output_arrays=output)

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]

tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('/model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

These are the warnings it will print during the conversion (even though I use both of the suggested flags):

```
W tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/python/tf_tfl_flatbuffer_helpers.cc:357] Ignored output_format.
2022-05-05 19:02:57.164878: W tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/python/tf_tfl_flatbuffer_helpers.cc:360] Ignored drop_control_dependency.
2022-05-05 19:02:57.225696: W tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/flatbuffer_export.cc:1892] TFLite interpreter needs to link Flex delegate in order to run the model since it contains the following Select TFop(s):
Flex ops: FlexAudioSpectrogram, FlexDecodeWav, FlexMfcc
Details:
        tf.AudioSpectrogram(tensor<16000x1xf32>) -> (tensor<1x97x513xf32>) : {device = "", magnitude_squared = true, stride = 160 : i64, window_size = 640 : i64}
        tf.DecodeWav(tensor<*x!tf_type.string>) -> (tensor<16000x1xf32>, tensor<i32>) : {desired_channels = 1 : i64, desired_samples = 16000 : i64, device = ""}
        tf.Mfcc(tensor<1x97x513xf32>, tensor<i32>) -> (tensor<1x97x40xf32>) : {dct_coefficient_count = 40 : i64, device = "", filterbank_channel_count = 40 : i64, lower_frequency_limit = 2.000000e+01 : f32, upper_frequency_limit = 4.000000e+03 : f32}
```

If I visualize the model using Netron it looks ok but when I try to load it on Android following this codelab: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/tflite-audio-classification-basic-android#0 it will crash:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error occurred when initializing AudioClassifier: AllocateTensors() failed.
```

The code is failing only when using this custom tflite. I guess something is amiss with the conversion... any ideas?

Update:
Here's the Android app's Gradle too:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-audio:0.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.7.0'
}
```

Top level gradle:

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name 'ossrh-snapshot'
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        mavenLocal()
    }
```

Comment: I believe the issue is not at the conversion but in the android code. Since you have used tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS you have to add a dependency at build.gradle file. Check https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#run_inference

Comment: I've updated the code with the gradle file. Unfortunately I still can't figure out what's wrong with it.